# b-table vue.js not working - showing all data

Tags: vue.js

I am working on a vuejs project, need to show data in a table with pagination and search.
here is my code

```
     <div class="table-responsive table-hover mb-0">
      <b-table
        :current-page="currentPage"
        :per-page="perPage"
        :items="activitiesData"
        :fields="fields"
        responsive="sm"
        :v-model:sort-by="sortBy"
        :v-model:sort-desc="sortDesc"
        :filter="filter"
        :filter-included-fields="filterOn"
        @filtered="onFiltered"
      ></b-table>
    </div>
        
            <b-pagination
              v-model="currentPage"
              :total-rows="rows"
              :per-page="perPage"
            ></b-pagination>
```

according to this code user will only see 2 records in a page and others when changing pagination . but for now showing all records in a page.
Please someone help me to solve this.

Comment: Please consider to remove all not necessary code to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using some code sandbox.